# Relation ManyToMany with Symfony 5 : do not save

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, arraycollection

For my project, I created 2 entities : Recipe & Ingredient. They are a ManyToMany relation.
[mysql shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Msju.png)

I generated everything from the console (entity & CRUD). But, I can't save ingredients for recipes, the field 'ingredients'do not save anything, just Date and Name.

I try add a "cascade={"persist"}" in my entity, but it does not work.
thank you in advance for your help !

Ingredient.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\IngredientRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=IngredientRepository::class)
 */
class Ingredient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Recette::class, inversedBy="ingredients",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $recette;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->recette = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Recette[]
     */
    public function getRecette(): Collection
    {
        return $this->recette;
    }

    public function addRecette(Recette $recette): self
    {
        if (!$this->recette->contains($recette)) {
            $this->recette[] = $recette;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRecette(Recette $recette): self
    {
        if ($this->recette->contains($recette)) {
            $this->recette->removeElement($recette);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;

    }
}
```

IngredientController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Ingredient;
use App\Form\IngredientType;
use App\Repository\IngredientRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/ingredient")
 */
class IngredientController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="ingredient_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(IngredientRepository $ingredientRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('ingredient/index.html.twig', [
            'ingredients' => $ingredientRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="ingredient_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $ingredient = new Ingredient();
        $form = $this->createForm(IngredientType::class, $ingredient);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($ingredient);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('ingredient_index');
        }

        return $this->render('ingredient/new.html.twig', [
            'ingredient' => $ingredient,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="ingredient_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Ingredient $ingredient): Response
    {
        return $this->render('ingredient/show.html.twig', [
            'ingredient' => $ingredient,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="ingredient_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Ingredient $ingredient): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(IngredientType::class, $ingredient);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('ingredient_index');
        }

        return $this->render('ingredient/edit.html.twig', [
            'ingredient' => $ingredient,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="ingredient_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Ingredient $ingredient): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$ingredient->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($ingredient);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('ingredient_index');
    }
}
```

Recette.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RecetteRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecetteRepository::class)
 */
class Recette
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $publishedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ingredient::class, mappedBy="recette",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $ingredients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ingredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublishedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publishedAt;
    }

    public function setPublishedAt(\DateTimeInterface $publishedAt): self
    {
        $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Ingredient[]
     */
    public function getIngredients(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ingredients;
    }

    public function addIngredient(Ingredient $ingredient): self
    {
        if (!$this->ingredients->contains($ingredient)) {
            $this->ingredients[] = $ingredient;
            $ingredient->addRecette($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIngredient(Ingredient $ingredient): self
    {
        if ($this->ingredients->contains($ingredient)) {
            $this->ingredients->removeElement($ingredient);
            $ingredient->removeRecette($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

RecetteController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Recette;
use App\Form\RecetteType;
use App\Repository\RecetteRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/recette")
 */
class RecetteController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="recette_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(RecetteRepository $recetteRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('recette/index.html.twig', [
            'recettes' => $recetteRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="recette_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $recette = new Recette();
        $form = $this->createForm(RecetteType::class, $recette);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($recette);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('recette_index');
        }

        return $this->render('recette/new.html.twig', [
            'recette' => $recette,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="recette_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Recette $recette): Response
    {
        return $this->render('recette/show.html.twig', [
            'recette' => $recette,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="recette_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Recette $recette): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(RecetteType::class, $recette);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('recette_index');
        }

        return $this->render('recette/edit.html.twig', [
            'recette' => $recette,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="recette_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Recette $recette): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$recette->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($recette);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('recette_index');
    }
}
```

RecetteType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Recette;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RecetteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('publishedAt')
            ->add('ingredients')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Recette::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relationship ManyToMany, one-way remove/add is not working.
For such manyToMany relationship, you have to call the remove/add methods from both entities
$recette->addIngredient($ingredients);
$Ingredients->addRecettes($recette);

Answer (score 0):

There should be another table called 'ingredient_recipe'. The many to many relationship items will be saved here.